# Community detection in extracted ego network using igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I used the igraph library installed in R software and I want to extract an ego-network from the network "Les Miserables".

Here is my code:

```
library("igraph")
lesmis<-read.graph("lesmis.gml", format="gml")
gavroche <- graph.neighborhood(lesmis, order = 2, nodes = which(V(lesmis)$label == "Gavroche"))
wc<-infomap.community(gavroche)
plot(wc, gavroche)
```

I get this error :

> Error in infomap.community(gavroche) : Not a graph object

here is the link of the gml file :
http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/netdata/lesmis.zip

Comment: `graph.neighborhood` returns a list of graphs, always, so you need to extract the first (and only) element.

Comment: Thank you, in fact, i want to extract the egocentric network of Gavroche as a graph and display the detected communities in output graph.

Answer (score 0):

I've reached this question just now searching for other theme.
I found that the object created by `graph.neighborhood` is not a graph itself but a list instead, that in turn contains your expected graph. Then you can replace:

```
wc <- infomap.community(gavroche[[1]])
plot(wc, gavroche[[1]])
```

And it must work.